# Run a method after some controllers Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I know Web API has filters that will let me run some logic before controller has run (if i decorate the controller) as well as delegating handlers that will let me plug into the request/response pipeline on both request and response.

My question is there something that will let me run custom logic after a controller has run as well as use method decoration to indicate which controllers are affected.

Something like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    [WillRunAfterControllerHasRun]
    public Domain.Codelink.CodeLink Add(Domain.Codelink.CodeLink newItem)
    {
        var rtrn = Mapper.Map<Domain.Codelink.CodeLink>(repo.Insert(Mapper.Map<EF.Codelink.CodeLink>(newItem)));


        return (rtrn);
    }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the same ActionFilters but instead of overrideing `OnActionExecuting` (that happens before the controller) you override `OnActionExecuted`

```
public class PostControllerAttrbute: ActionFilterAttribute
{        

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        //things...

        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
    }
}
```